# Get translation of words directly in cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a column with (for example) 30 words in French and I want to translate them to English. Each word is in a cell. I usually look them up in dict.cc and choose the best one but the copy/pasting is annoying.

Is it possible to do the follwing?: By moving over the cell (french word) a small box should pop up with all available translations from dict.cc and I want to choose one.

Comment: Short answer: Yes - it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Their [terms of use](http://www.dict.cc/?s=about%3A) say "All other ways of usage, particularly automated requests (parsing) require express permission" so downloading the database as suggested by Richard Dana seems like the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to download the dict.cc Database (FR->EN) (or any other language for that matter) from their page. You would then have to integrate the Data into your File.

Currently the FR->EN File is approximately 667,410KB saved as a Text File. Pasting it to Excel will give you a 3 Column Sheet (1. Column FR, 2. Column EN, 3. Special Conditions).

With a Data Validation or a Lookup you are able to bind the words.

[http://www.dict.cc/?s=about%3Awordlist](http://www.dict.cc/?s=about%3awordlist)
13. Vokabeldatenbank

Hope this helps you.